# Doubts about Heisenberg principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am currently immersed in the study of quantum mechanics for an upcoming exam, specifically focusing on the demonstration of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. While I believe I can successfully replicate the demonstration, I find the process somewhat circular, as it appears we are demonstrating it because we already know what we are aiming to prove.

Cohen suggests considering a ket, denoted as $|\psi\rangle = (Q + i\lambda P)|\phi\rangle$, and subsequently computing $<\psi|\psi>$. Through algebraic manipulation, we arrive at the well-known formula. However, the question arises: why does the state vector $|\psi\rangle$ have this particular form? I am seeking a deeper understanding beyond the pragmatic "because it works." What fundamental principles or concepts underlie the choice of $|\psi\rangle$ in this demonstration?

Comment: What you write makes no sense: On the LHS there is a vector, on the RHS there is an operator. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, you seem to ask two questions in a single post, which is usually off-topic. But your second question was asked here several times.

Comment: sorry I make a typo, and also deleted the other question

Comment: It's simply mathematics: $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle \ge 0$.

Comment: Good. But what is your question now, exactly? The book, presumably, makes use of the fact that the norm is non-negative for all vectors. Hence, in particular, it must be for all vectors of the form you wrote, which then gives the HUP for all $\phi$ (ignoring subtle mathematics, but this is the logic behind it).

Comment: The question is why it has to be like that?. I know that the norm must be nonnegative and that leads to the demonstration. But I assume that if use another $\psi$ you can not demonstrate the principle or can you?. My question is about the election of $\psi$ as a linear combination of the two Observables Q and P

Comment: It might help to outline the proof that you're thinking about here. I *suspect* that you are thinking that this derivation is about $\lvert \psi \rangle$, when really it's about $\lvert\varphi\rangle$, but I can't be sure.  What I mean is, we're trying to develop the HUP given that the state of the system is $\lvert\varphi\rangle$, and we *construct* the vector $\lvert \psi \rangle$ along the way in the proof. For that reason, $\lvert \psi \rangle$ doesn't really have any physical meaning. This might be unsatisfying...

Comment: ...but of all undergraduate physics, QM has the largest inferential gap between the mathematical formalism and the physical results and interpretations of calculations, and so we just have to get used to *just doing the math* sometimes.

Comment: By the way, derivations of HUP often (always?) use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which also isn't necessarily *physical*, but at least has a nice intuitive meaning. The CS inequality, properly rearranged, just says that the *component* of a vector in an orthonormal basis has to be smaller in length than the length of the vector itself.

Comment: that´s the answer that i was looking for

Comment: Cohen? Do you mean Cohen-Tannoudji? Which book and which page?

Comment: QUANTUM MECHANICS
olume I
Basic Concepts, Tools, and Applications
Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, Bernard Diu,
and Franck Laloë pg 289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to $Q, P$.  It's a mathematical theorem, a variation of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

For $\phi$ a vector in an inner-product space, denote $\|\phi\|=\sqrt{\langle\phi,\phi\rangle}$.

Claim: Let $\phi,\psi$ be two vectors in an inner-product space.  Then $|\text{Im}\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|\le\|\phi\|\|\psi\|$.

Proof: Let $\lambda$ be a real number and consider the vector $\phi+i\lambda\psi$.  Then
$$0\le\|\phi+i\lambda\psi\|^2=\|\phi\|^2-2\lambda\text{Im}\langle\phi|\psi\rangle+\lambda^2\|\psi\|^2\tag{1}$$
Considering $\phi,\psi$ fixed, the RHS of $(1)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$ which is $\ge 0$.  Therefore the discriminant of the polynomial must be $\le 0$.
$$\Delta = \left(-2\text{Im}\langle\phi|\psi\rangle\right)^2-4\|\phi\|^2\|\psi\|^2\le 0$$
and from this $\left|\text{Im}\langle\phi|\psi\rangle\right|^2\le\|\phi\|^2\|\psi\|^2$ which gives the claim after taking square root.

Now you can take this theorem and use it as a building block for proving the Heisenberg uncertainty principle without direct use of an exression $Q+i\lambda P$.